# How to code date of birth range to cause an action?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build a zodiac sign app for class. I am using a `UIDatePicker` and an `UIImageView` to display the image once the user picks a date (date range, say if the date of birth is between a certain date). The zodiac will be revealed in text and also the image appears. So far I have my user interface and all the images ready, but I am not sure how to go with the main code for it to function properly.

```
var zodiac = ["Aqurius", "Pisces", ...]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    zodiacSign.text  = zodiac[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `@IBAction` by ctrl-dragging from your `UIDatePicker` in Interface Builder to your view controller.

```
@IBAction func datePickerChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

  let date = datePicker.date
  // configure your labels and images according to date
}
```